# Fallacy - where is the mistake?

Tags: integration, paradoxes

Could anyone help me to find the mistake in this fallacy? Because the actual result for $I$ is $\pi/2$

\begin{equation}
I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^{2} x \; \textrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos x \cos x \; \textrm{d}x
\end{equation}
substitution:
\begin{equation}
\sin x = u
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\cos x \; \textrm{d}x = u
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\cos x = \cos (\arcsin x)
\end{equation}
and the limits:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
x &= 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad u=0 \\
x &= \pi \quad \Rightarrow \quad u=0
\end{split}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation} 
I = \int_{0}^{0} \cos (\arcsin u) \textrm{d}u
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I=0
\end{equation}

Comment: There is no paradox. You've stumbled upon the dark secret of mathematicians from the past two centuries. Math is totally inconsistent! ;-)

Comment: you have a couple of typos (in the second and third statements after the word "substitution"), though that doesn't affect the outcome

Comment: One can get into trouble sometimes with a non-monotone substitution. But that's not the problem here: the antiderivative is wrong.

Comment: Have you thought about accepting an answer to this question? Looking at your profile, I see you haven't accepted an answer to any of your questions. Do you know about this option? If not, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), and for a detailed discussion, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Note, you don't have to accept an answer if you feel your question hasn't been fully dealt with, but in that case, you might want to comment on the existing answers, letting them know what you still don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in using $\cos x = \cos \sin^{-1} x$. Arcsine is not a single valued function on $x=[0,\pi]$. In the conventional sense, it's not defined outside of $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. You can only do a $u$ substitution using a one-to-one function.

Answer (score -1):

if $\sin(x)=u$ we get $x=\arcsin(u)$ and $dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$ thus we get
$\int \cos(x)^2dx=\int 1-\sin(x)^2dx=\int \sqrt{1-u^2}du$

Comment: And what about the limits of integration?

Answer (score -1):

You've messed something up...I can't quite see it, but this is how I would solve the problem:

\begin{equation}
I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^2\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{2}\right)dx
\end{equation}
via using the trigonometric identity. Your u-substitution is wrong btw...you cannot substitute $u=\sin\left(x\right)$ since there is no $\sin\left(x\right)$ in the integrand, and it isn't equivalent to anything either unless you change your bounds of integration which is pointless.